# How to invoke functions in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle

Here is a theory I've taken from Isabelle Tutorial. It has ways to prove theorems but I was wondering how one would call the app function below with two lists.

```
theory ToyList
imports Main
begin
     datatype 'a list = Nil |  Cons 'a "'a list"

     fun app :: "'a list ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'a list"  where 
                 "app Nil ys   = ys" |
                 "app (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x (app xs ys)"
```

I tried theorem app_test[simp] : "app (xs @ ys ) @ zs =  xs @ ys @ zs" and other ways but didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? What do you want to do? Evaluate the function on two concrete example lists? Then you can do something like `value "app (Cons 1 Nil) (Cons 2 Nil)"`

Comment: I mean how do I use the app function with lists? Yes, I mean evaluate on example lists.

Comment: As I said: you can use the `value` command, which I am sure is explained in the tutorial as well. You can also set up a lemma like `app (Cons 1 Nil) (Cons 2 Nil) = Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)` and prove it with `simp`.